# Comparing determinants

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ so that $a_{ii}\ne0$. Define $D$ be the diagonal matrix of $A$, $L$ be the strictly lower triangular matrix of $A$, and $U$ be the strictly upper triangular matrix of $A$. Then we have $A=D+L+U$. I'm trying to show that

$$\det\left[ (I-\omega L)^{-1}((1-\omega)I+\omega U)\right]=\det\left[ (D+\omega L)^{-1}((1-\omega)D-\omega U)\right]$$ for all $\omega$. I've been doing numerical simulation on this and the result suggested that the above equality holds but I can't prove it analytically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $I - \omega L$ is triangular, hence $\det (I - \omega L) = 1$.
Similarly, $\det (D + \omega L) = \det D$.

Note that $(1-\omega)I+\omega U$ is triangular, hence $\det ((1-\omega)I+\omega U) = (1- \omega)^n$.

Similarly, $(1-\omega)D-\omega U$ is triangular, hence $\det ((1-\omega)D-\omega U) = (1 - \omega)^n \det D$.

Comment: Do we have relation $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$?

Comment: Yes. This is a fairly elementary property of determinants!

Comment: As your matrix is $n\times n$ we can use it for square matrices not others